# How to neural network differentiate between images in flatten rows

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am learning from the below website

http://cs231n.github.io/classification/

I want to understand how neural network differentiate the images.

```
Xtr, Ytr, Xte, Yte = load_CIFAR10('data/cifar10/') # a magic function we provide
# flatten out all images to be one-dimensional
Xtr_rows = Xtr.reshape(Xtr.shape[0], 32 * 32 * 3) # Xtr_rows becomes 50000 x 3072
Xte_rows = Xte.reshape(Xte.shape[0], 32 * 32 * 3) # Xte_rows becomes 10000 x 3072
```

For example here we have 50000 training examples, but when we flatten it
it becomes 50000 x 3072, it is just numbers how neural network understands
which is the first image, which is second image etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dataset you have 50000 images with 32x32 pixels and 3 channels.

Flattening means that you transform each image into a one-dimensional vector.

Each image contains 32x32x3 = 3072 values. So after this step you have an array of 50000 vectors with 3072 elements each.

The first image is the first element in Xtr_rows. That's how the computer knows.

And yes neural networks as any other computer program are just crunching numbers.